# Trying to build an app and every time I sync with Gradle I get the same 3 errors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

one that says, Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.1.2/appcompat-v7-21.1.2.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.1.2/appcompat-v7-21.1.2.jar

     file:/C:/Users/Richard/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.1.2/appcompat-v7-21.1.2.pom
     file:/C:/Users/Richard/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.1.2/appcompat-v7-21.1.2.jar
     file:/C:/Users/Richard/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.1.2/appcompat-v7-21.1.2.pom
     file:/C:/Users/Richard/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.1.2/appcompat-v7-21.1.2.jar
 Required by:
     MyApplication:app:unspecified
```

And another one that says:

```
Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.2
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: Link your gradle file contents please.

Comment: Check what you have in SDK manager - you might not have that dependency, or you've updated to a newer one, removed the older one, but not updated the version in your gradle file (under compile).

Answer (score 1):

The Appcompat v 21.1.2 doesn't exist.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) the releases.

You can use:

You can use one of these:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```